# nginx redirect to a false domain

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, configuration

Hello I am trying to use a subdomain, but the redirection fails.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name sub.domain.de;
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://ip;
   }
}
```

It redirects me to google, because i input google in proxy_pass before.
same for port 443

what can I do to stop the redirecting to the old test-path?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your browser's cache. Always clear the browser's cache between changes to the server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Maybe you have not restarted nginx after changing the config. When changing config, restart with `systemctl restart nginx`.
- Maybe google replied with a 301 permanent redirect. Browsers essentially cache 301s forever. Clear your browser's cache, that should fix it.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know what happen but I think you are right.The redirection is gone.